# Can you use Visual Studio 2008 to develop for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

Can I continue to use Visual Studio 2008 to develop for SharePoint 2010? Or do I need Visual Studio 2010?

I understand that VS2010 makes it easier to deploy and debug but other than that what are the benefits of moving to VS2010? [Is VS2010 slower](http://blog.furuknap.net/why-i-stick-with-visual-studio-2008-for-sharepoint-2010-development)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that developing in VS2010 is quicker, but that is because of the ease you can debug & deploy, hence you spend less time creating/running a script to go ahead and package your project into a solution which is then deployed. You also have good intellisense of CAML, which again saves time.

It's not that VS2010 *runs* faster or slower, it's that it lets you develop faster.

Comment: You can get intellisense of CAML in 2008 just as easily by copying over the schemas from the hive.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend going to 2010. You'll get the new SPIs (SharePoint Items) and deploying is tons better.  I haven't noticed it being slower.  The WPF ui in VS2010 is much better on the eyes too.  All of our devs upgraded, whether they are programming for SharePoint or not.

Comment: hi Rob, is there any  MSFT provided links wherein i can strongly say, VS 2010 is the best IDE for  SP 2010 dev?

Comment: can you pls comment

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2008 works just fine. Just make sure you get something like [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/).

Have a look at [our series about porting WSPBuilder projects from SharePoint 2007 to 2010](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html).

Comment: Second this.  VS 2008 will work just fine if you don't have access to 2010.  I even prefer WSPBuilder to VS2010 packaging which likes to add its own naming scheme for features.

Comment: Ill second it, but after first doing alot of SP2010 work on VS2010 and now having to go back to VS2008 and WSP, I must say I hate it combined to the ease of use with VS2010 OOB tools combined with the excellent CKS:DEV tools